# Is 400 the appropriate error code for OAuth verification errors (http)?

Tags: http, facebook-graph-api, oauth, response

Hi guys : What should the correct http response code be for an request which, although well-formed, is includes an invalid oauth token ?

**The error code 400 seems misleading,** since an invalid oauth is, I believe, not malformed request.

Strangely, it is the case that facebook oauth tokens (if invalid), cause an api return of result in the return if  a 400 response code....

Comment: Define "invalid oauth". Using a wrong/missing client or scope could as well be considered a malformed request (however above HTTP level).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct.

`401 Unauthorized` should be the primary choice for response status code in your example.

**EDIT:**

I spent some time browsing the OAuth2 draft, and it looks like they specify the following when client authentication fails:

- normally MUST respond with `400 Bad Request`, but
- MAY respond with `401 Unauthorized`, and
- MUST respond with `401 Unauthorized` if authentication was attempted using the `Authorization` request header. If so it must also include a `WWW-Authenticate` in the response.

Comment: Hmmm... any thoughts on why facebook implements a 400 return on bad oauths ?

Comment: Well, having implemented an OAuth provider myself, I can only say that I didn't think it was trivial to get all the response codes right. I had to refactor quite a bit to get to where I wanted. In facebooks case I can only surmise that they have overlooked it, or simply not deemed it worthwhile doing. On a side note: there are over a 1000 open bugs on developers.facebook.com, and none of them seem to deal with this issue.

Comment: On my reading of RFC 6749 the invalid token case falls under `invalid_grant` rather than `invalid_client`, and so should be a `400 Bad Request`, with no `WWW-Authenticate`. I agree the RFC is really unclear, though.

Comment: Correction: [RFC 6749 section 5.2](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-5.2) only refers to requests for tokens, not to requests _with_ tokens. It looks like [RFC 6750 section 3](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6750#section-3) does specify `401 Unauthorized` and require a `WWW-Authenticate`.

Answer (score 5):

From http://oauth.net/core/1.0a/#http_codes

```
HTTP 400 Bad Request
    Unsupported parameter
    Unsupported signature method
    Missing required parameter
    Duplicated OAuth Protocol Parameter
HTTP 401 Unauthorized
    Invalid Consumer Key
    Invalid / expired Token
    Invalid signature
    Invalid / used nonce
```

So the 401 is right.

Comment: That's for Oauth 1.0 - it may be different for Oauth 2.0 (which Facebook uses) - http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-22 may specify otherwise (I haven't read the specs so i'm not sure)